# Consuming ASP.NET Web API in C#

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5

ASP.NET Web API seems to lack the service contract / data contract features of WCF web services which would have generated a wsdl that could be used to generate proxy classes. I'm wondering whether Web API is intended for consumption in a service-oriented architecture or if it's meant simply for Ajax consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API (as far as I know) does not support WSDL generation. If you absolutely require a WSDL, [WCF REST](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20REST) **might** be an option, though no longer supported.

Service-oriented architecture does not require the use of SOAP or reliance on a WSDL and RESTful services aren't restricted to being useful only for AJAX requests. There are quite a few RESTful web service [client libraries available from nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) that makes interacting with these services easier. Though it might not be as simple as using code-gen, creating a library of POCO classes you can share with other C# clients also makes things easier. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. My research is leaning toward the idea that the API ought not be too restrictive if using REST vs. SOAP. Consider, e.g., "hackable" urls vs a SOAP service that throws an error if one field is improperly formatted or missing.